# Blank screen on boot, even with onboard graphics

Tags: boot, graphics-card, post, cmos, blank-screen

So I have a custom-built PC with an Intel motherboard, an Intel i5 processor and a GTX 560 Ti connected via a PCIe x16 slot.

Whenever I turn on the computer with the graphics card plugged in, my monitor turns on (power turns from orange to blue) but the screen is absolutely blank. I don't hear any beep sounds either.

I removed the graphics card and tried to boot up from onboard graphics. The monitor did not turn on and this time, I got two beeps, a pause and another two beeps. I looked this up online and this beep pattern means that the graphics has failed. But since I have no graphics card connected, this seems to be a problem with my onboard graphics.

I repeated the above two tests after resetting the CMOS (both by reseating the battery and by using the jumper): I got the same results.

I'm guessing that the problem is either with my CPU or my motherboard. I'm not sure of a way to isolate the problem to either of these components.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I guess your first words answer already the question what is the problem: "I have a custom-built PC" ;)

Comment: LOL. I hope you're kidding. :p